# JAXB - Exclude required element in XML output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a JAXB/JPA data model that reads XML, generates the JAXB model and stores into the DB, with some elements that are required in the DB and need to be present in the XML string.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Environment")
public class Environment {

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String status;

    //... more elements, getters/setters etc
}
```

But for reading from the DB and generating the XML output I want to exclude some elements from the XML string, in my example the `status` field. How can this be done? The only way of excluding elements I know is to annotate them with `@XmlTransient`, which doesn't work here because it causes these elements to be excluded from the input XML parsing and thus they wouldn't be stored into the DB.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Environment")
public class Environment {

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    // This doesnt work for my case
    @XmlTransient
    private String status;

    //... more elements, getters/setters etc
}
```

So the two options seem mutually exclusive to me, can I achieve my use case in any other easy way? Or do I need to do some custom marshaling?

Comment: your question isn't clear. You are saying, you want that field, but you don't want ???

Comment: I think my question is very clear. The field needs to be set in the DB and must be present in the input XML. But when reading from the DB and generating the output XML, the element should not be serialized to XML.

Comment: If it was, then you should have received many response by now. You have mixed your statement, which is creating confusion. Anyway, I got you point now. But, I'm still trying to understand your scenario.